# Humanized or natural number sorting of mixed word-and-number strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, collation, natural-sort

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12916212/398670) by [Sivaram Chintalapudi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1176139/sivaram-chintalapudi), I'm interested in whether it's practical in PostgreSQL to do [natural - or "humanized" - sorting](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html) " of strings that contain a mixture of multi-digit numbers and words/letters. There is no fixed pattern of words and numbers in the strings, and there may be more than one multi-digit number in a string.

The only place I've seen this done routinely is in the Mac OS's Finder, which sorts filenames containing mixed numbers and words naturally, placing "20" after "3", not before it.

The collation order desired would be produced by an algorithm that split each string into blocks at letter-number boundaries, then ordered each part, treating letter-blocks with normal collation and number-blocks as integers for collation purposes. So:

`'AAA2fred'` would become `('AAA',2,'fred')` and `'AAA10bob'` would become `('AAA',10,'bob')`. These can then be sorted as desired:

```
regress=# WITH dat AS ( VALUES ('AAA',2,'fred'), ('AAA',10,'bob') )
regress-# SELECT dat FROM dat ORDER BY dat;
     dat      
--------------
 (AAA,2,fred)
 (AAA,10,bob)
(2 rows)
```

as compared to the usual string collation ordering:

```
regress=# WITH dat AS ( VALUES ('AAA2fred'), ('AAA10bob') )
regress-# SELECT dat FROM dat ORDER BY dat;
    dat     
------------
 (AAA10bob)
 (AAA2fred)
(2 rows)
```

However, the record comparison approach doesn't generalize because Pg won't compare ROW(..) constructs or records of unequal numbers of entries.

Given the sample data [in this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c1700/1) the default en_AU.UTF-8 collation produces the ordering:

```
1A, 10A, 2A, AAA10B, AAA11B, AAA1BB, AAA20B, AAA21B, X10C10, X10C2, X1C1, X1C10, X1C3, X1C30, X1C4, X2C1
```

but I want:

```
1A, 2A, 10A, AAA1BB, AAA10B, AAA11B, AAA20B, AAA21B, X1C1, X1C3, X1C4, X1C10, X1C30, X2C1, X10C10, X10C2
```

I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.1 at the moment, but 9.2-only suggestions would be fine. I'm interested in advice on how to achieve an efficient string-splitting method, and how to then compare the resulting split data in the alternating string-then-number collation described. Or, of course, on entirely different and better approaches that don't require splitting strings.

PostgreSQL doesn't seem to support comparator functions, otherwise this could be done fairly easily with a recursive comparator and something like `ORDER USING comparator_fn` and a `comparator(text,text)` function. Alas, that syntax is imaginary.

**Update:** [Blog post on the topic](http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/10/natural-sorting-example-of-utility-of.html).

Comment: Note: IIRC, Linux has a "numsort" function to do this kind of thing. Without collation woes, of course. Intended for version strings. (could even stem from BSD ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser Interesting. I'm not seeing a manpage for it and there's no `\<numsort\>` in /usr/include, though, so I suspect it must have a somewhat different name.

Comment: It was from the top of my head. I'll do some googling. BRB. Could be implemented as a compariso-operator, BTW (without the array splitting)

Comment: **versionsort()** it is in the scandir man page.

Comment: @wildplasser Nice find. It looks like the actual function that does the work is [`strverscmp`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_strverscmp.htm). So one possible approach is to write a new ordering operator as a C extension based on `strverscmp` - not impossible, but non-portable and probably not ideal. I'll put it on my "C extensions for fun" todo though (http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/08/generating-random-bytea-values-in.html). `strverscmp` doesn't respect the current collation, so it'd produce wrong results if the words were (say) polish, though.

Comment: I remembered because I tried to build a function myself (I like to construct state machines in my leasure time ;-) I could not find it here at home, maybe it is at work somewhere. It 'll be friday anyway tomorow. Good night!

Comment: There are some truly fascinating comments on that CodingHorror post (linked in question). For example, the Mac OS Finder's natural sort is provided by [the International Components for Unicode (ICU)](http://site.icu-project.org/) library using the `UCOL_NUMERIC_COLLATION` flag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Building on your test data, but this works with arbitrary data. This works with any number of elements in the string.

Register a composite type made up of one `text` and one `integer` value once per database. I call it `ai`:

`CREATE TYPE ai AS (a text, i int);`

The trick is to form an array of `ai` from each value in the column.

`regexp_matches()` with the pattern `(\D*)(\d*)` and the `g` option returns one row for every combination of letters and numbers. Plus one irrelevant dangling  row with two empty strings `'{"",""}'` Filtering or suppressing it would just add cost. Aggregate this into an array, after replacing empty strings (`''`) with `0` in the `integer` component (as `''` cannot be cast to `integer`).

`NULL` values sort first - or you have to special case them - or use the whole shebang in a `STRICT` function like @Craig proposes.

### Postgres 9.4 or later

```
SELECT data
FROM   alnum
ORDER  BY ARRAY(SELECT ROW(x[1], CASE x[2] WHEN '' THEN '0' ELSE x[2] END)::ai
                FROM regexp_matches(data, '(\D*)(\d*)', 'g') x)
        , data;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0f53af444360677724068636723a69ea)*

### Postgres 9.1 (original answer)

Tested with PostgreSQL 9.1.5, where `regexp_replace()` had a slightly different behavior.

```
SELECT data
FROM  (
    SELECT ctid, data, regexp_matches(data, '(\D*)(\d*)', 'g') AS x
    FROM   alnum
    ) x
GROUP  BY ctid, data   -- ctid as stand-in for a missing pk
ORDER  BY regexp_replace (left(data, 1), '[0-9]', '0')
        , array_agg(ROW(x[1], CASE x[2] WHEN '' THEN '0' ELSE x[2] END)::ai)
        , data         -- for special case of trailing 0
```

Add `regexp_replace (left(data, 1), '[1-9]', '0')` as first `ORDER BY` item to take care of leading digits and empty strings.

<strike>If special characters like `{}()"',` can occur, you'd have to escape those accordingly.</strike>
  @Craig's suggestion to use a `ROW` expression takes care of that.

<strike>BTW, this won't execute in sqlfiddle, but it does in my db cluster. JDBC is not up to it. sqlfiddle complains:</strike>

> Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Array.getArrayImpl(long,int,Map) is
>   not yet implemented.

This has since been fixed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fad6e/1

Comment: Funny; we were almost certainly working on these very similar approaches simultaneously. `\D` is much better than the character class I was using.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I guess, one has to end up somewhere near this solution (with plain SQL). So it's not that surprising that you were steering in the same direction. It *is* pretty advanced stuff, though. PostgreSQL art, kind of. :)

Comment: Yeah, I managed to trigger that error too. It looks like PgJDBC doesn't like arrays of composite types. I'll add a test case to the PgJDBC test suite and TODO it on https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues . Casting to `text` works around it.

Comment: Instead of the `replace` and `translate` it might be safer to use a ROW() constructor and array subscripting. See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b893e/8

Comment: @CraigRinger: I updated with your idea to use a row expression, plus added `left(data, 1)` to fix the order for leading digits or empty strings. Only `NULL` values remain unsolved - they are filtered by the `regexp_matches()` step which produces "no row" for `NULL` values. You would have to `UNION ALL` `NULL` values back to the result if you want them in there.

Comment: To handle NULLs I'd probably wrap it in a `STRICT IMMUTABLE` SQL function, as that'd not only handle NULLs automatically but also allow indexing on the expression.

Comment: @CraigRinger: `STRICT` would take care of it nicely - I see you are aiming for the index on an expression. In pure SQL you'd need the special case for `NULL`. BTW, there was still a glitch in the `ORDER BY` for leading numbers / empty strings. I think I silenced that for good now.

Comment: Nice. Thanks; you don't need to go so all-out on this, but it's certainly interesting. Just posted about this topic btw: http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/10/natural-sorting-example-of-utility-of.html

Answer (score 15):

I faced this same problem, and I wanted to wrap the solution in a function so I could re-use it easily. I created the following function to achieve a 'human style' sort order in Postgres.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION human_sort(text)
  RETURNS text[] AS
$BODY$   
  /* Split the input text into contiguous chunks where no numbers appear,
     and contiguous chunks of only numbers. For the numbers, add leading 
     zeros to 20 digits, so we can use one text array, but sort the 
     numbers as if they were big integers.

       For example, human_sort('Run 12 Miles') gives
            {'Run ', '00000000000000000012', ' Miles'}
  */
  select array_agg(
    case
      when a.match_array[1]::text is not null 
        then a.match_array[1]::text         
      else lpad(a.match_array[2]::text, 20::int, '0'::text)::text                                      
    end::text)
    from (
      select regexp_matches(
        case when $1 = '' then null else $1 end, E'(\\D+)|(\\d+)', 'g'
      ) AS match_array      
    ) AS a  
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

tested to work on Postgres 8.3.18 and 9.3.5

- No recursion, should be faster than recursive solutions
- Can be used in just the order by clause, don't have to deal with primary key or ctid
- Works for any select (don't even need a PK or ctid)
- Simpler than some other solutions, should be easier to extend and maintain
- Suitable for use in a functional index to improve performance
- Works on Postgres v8.3 or higher
- Allows an unlimited number of text/number alternations in the input
- Uses just one regex, should be faster than versions with multiple regexes
- Numbers longer than 20 digits are ordered by their first 20 digits

Here's an example usage:

```sql
select * from (values 
  ('Books 1', 9),
  ('Book 20 Chapter 1', 8),
  ('Book 3 Suffix 1', 7),
  ('Book 3 Chapter 20', 6),
  ('Book 3 Chapter 2', 5),
  ('Book 3 Chapter 1', 4),
  ('Book 1 Chapter 20', 3),
  ('Book 1 Chapter 3', 2),
  ('Book 1 Chapter 1', 1),
  ('', 0),
  (null::text, 0)
) as a(name, sort)
order by human_sort(a.name)
-----------------------------
|name               |  sort |
-----------------------------
|                   |   0   |
|                   |   0   |
|Book 1 Chapter 1   |   1   |
|Book 1 Chapter 3   |   2   |
|Book 1 Chapter 20  |   3   |
|Book 3 Chapter 1   |   4   |
|Book 3 Chapter 2   |   5   |
|Book 3 Chapter 20  |   6   |
|Book 3 Suffix 1    |   7   |
|Book 20 Chapter 1  |   8   |
|Books 1            |   9   |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: +1 for contributing your useful input so clearly and helpfully. Thankyou. Now go upgrade! 8.3 is obsolete and it will soon be unsupported, with no security updates or bug fixes. It's also a pain to work with, missing all sorts of performance and usability features.

Comment: Tested and working on 10.4. This is the only non-extension solution I've found that works. As a plus, it requires no external types or tables and seems to work with any arbitrary data.

Comment: Thanks rintaun! I have used this solution in production for the last 5 years and it's still going strong with no issues.

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 8):

Adding this answer late because it looked like everyone else was unwrapping into arrays or some such. Seemed excessive.

```
CREATE FUNCTION rr(text,int) RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace($1, '[0-9]+', repeat('0',$2) || '\&', 'g'), 
    '[0-9]*([0-9]{' || $2 || '})', 
    '\1', 
    'g'
)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT t,rr(t,9) FROM mixed ORDER BY t;
      t       |             rr              
--------------+-----------------------------
 AAA02free    | AAA000000002free
 AAA10bob     | AAA000000010bob
 AAA2bbb03boo | AAA000000002bbb000000003boo
 AAA2bbb3baa  | AAA000000002bbb000000003baa
 AAA2fred     | AAA000000002fred
(5 rows)

(reverse-i-search)`OD': SELECT crypt('richpass','$2$08$aJ9ko0uKa^C1krIbdValZ.dUH8D0R0dj8mqte0Xw2FjImP5B86ugC');
richardh=> 
richardh=> SELECT t,rr(t,9) FROM mixed ORDER BY rr(t,9);
      t       |             rr              
--------------+-----------------------------
 AAA2bbb3baa  | AAA000000002bbb000000003baa
 AAA2bbb03boo | AAA000000002bbb000000003boo
 AAA2fred     | AAA000000002fred
 AAA02free    | AAA000000002free
 AAA10bob     | AAA000000010bob
(5 rows)
```

I'm not claiming two regexps are the most efficient way to do this, but rr() is immutable (for fixed length) so you can index it. Oh - this is 9.1

Of course, with plperl you could just evaluate the replacement to pad/trim it in one go. But then with perl you've always got just-one-more-option (TM) than any other approach :-)

Answer (score 5):

The following function splits a string into an array of (word,number) pairs of arbitrary length. If the string begins with a number then the first entry will have a `NULL` word.

```
CREATE TYPE alnumpair AS (wordpart text,numpart integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION regexp_split_numstring_depth_pairs(instr text)
RETURNS alnumpair[] AS $$
WITH x(match) AS (SELECT regexp_matches($1, '(\D*)(\d+)(.*)'))
SELECT
  ARRAY[(CASE WHEN match[1] = '' THEN '0' ELSE match[1] END, match[2])::alnumpair] || (CASE 
  WHEN match[3] = '' THEN
    ARRAY[]::alnumpair[]
  ELSE 
    regexp_split_numstring_depth_pairs(match[3]) 
  END)
FROM x;$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;
```

allowing PostgreSQL's composite type sorting to come into play:

```
SELECT data FROM alnum ORDER BY regexp_split_numstring_depth_pairs(data);
```

and producing the expected result, as per [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f4243/1). I've adopted Erwin's substitution of `0` for the empty string in all strings beginning with a number so that numbers sort first; it's cleaner than using `ORDER BY left(data,1), regexp_split_numstring_depth_pairs(data)`.

While the function is probably horrifically slow it can at least be used in an expression index.

That was fun!

Comment: I made numbers sort first by substituting `0` instead of `NULL`, which sorts first within numbers and letters alike, at least in all collations known to me.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Good idea using `0`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I plan on using this function for one of my production servers, would it be a good idea. Also what would be the best way to index the colum. I need this for only 1 table having a varchar(250) column

Comment: @Akash If at all possible, fix your data model so that this isn't necessary. If you can't, then you could create a functional index on the column and then `ORDER BY` that function expression. Performance ... well, try it and see.

Answer (score 3):

```
create table dat(val text)
insert into dat ( VALUES ('BBB0adam'), ('AAA10fred'), ('AAA2fred'), ('AAA2bob') );

select 
  array_agg( case when z.x[1] ~ E'\\d' then lpad(z.x[1],10,'0') else z.x[1] end ) alnum_key
from (
  SELECT ctid, regexp_matches(dat.val, E'(\\D+|\\d+)','g') as x
  from dat
) z
group by z.ctid
order by alnum_key;

       alnum_key       
-----------------------
 {AAA,0000000002,bob}
 {AAA,0000000002,fred}
 {AAA,0000000010,fred}
 {BBB,0000000000,adam}
```

Worked on this for almost an hour and posted without looking -- I see Erwin arrived at a similar place.  Ran into the same "could not find array type for data type text[]" trouble as @Clodoaldo. Had a lot of trouble getting the cleanup exercise to not agg all the rows until I thought of grouping by the ctid (which feels like cheating really -- and doesn't work on a psuedo table as in the OP example `WITH dat AS ( VALUES ('AAA2fred'), ('AAA10bob') )
...`).  It would be nicer if array_agg could accept a set-producing subselect.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. It's an interesting problem, and I agree that the array_agg solution is a challenge.

Comment: +1 This is nice. There's the one remaining issue that the maximum number of digits is hard-coded. Then again, `integer` errors out after 10 digits, too. But you can just move on to `bigint` or `numeric` with that.

Comment: Not sure why the array_agg here - you can do this with just regexps - see my answer below.

Comment: @RichardHuxton why? well, your regexp_replace approach is clever, but I find it more obscure to read and I'll bet you a few bucks it's computationally more expensive as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a RegEx guru, but I can work it to some extent. Enough to produce this answer.

It will handle up to 2 numeric values within the content.  I don't think OSX goes further than that, if it even handles 2.

```
WITH parted AS (
  select data,
         substring(data from '([A-Za-z]+).*') part1,
         substring('a'||data from '[A-Za-z]+([0-9]+).*') part2,
         substring('a'||data from '[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+([A-Za-z]+).*') part3,
         substring('a'||data from '[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+([0-9]+).*') part4
    from alnum
)
  select data
    from parted
order by part1,
         cast(part2 as int),
         part3,
         cast(part4 as int),
         data;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ace2d/15/0)

Comment: Yep, the challenge is to generalize it to strings of arbitrary numbers of word-number alternations. For any given fixed number it's possible to do by writing individual splitting operations, albeit inefficiently. Thanks, though.

Comment: I was going to go for "any number of alternations" using regexp_matches and it will produce them in rows which can be concatenated back for sorting. If regexp_matches produced 2 columns, one with the sequence number, this would be a lot easier.

Comment: Ooh, that's an interesting idea. Use a recursive CTE based on matching of `(\w*)(\d+)(.*)` on the remainder of the last match.

Comment: The other thing about generalising it is that you'll be building a solution waiting for a problem. I can't imagine a use case for having to sort on a 7-part alpha-numeric alternating string.

Comment: Nor can I, frankly, I'm posting this because (a) it's an interesting problem and (b) it'll help Sivaram out by directing attention and less generalized solutions.

Comment: `it's an interesting problem` Smells like Code Golf and a cue for `"Close Question"`

Comment: Fair point; it's certainly borderline. OTOH, I do have an application for the sort, and I'm reluctant to go for one that just craps out after an arbitrary number of alternations.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is a combination of various ideas presented in other answers, as well as some ideas from the [classic solution](http://www.rhodiumtoad.org.uk/junk/naturalsort.sql):

```
create function natsort(s text) returns text immutable language sql as $$
  select string_agg(r[1] || E'\x01' || lpad(r[2], 20, '0'), '')
  from regexp_matches(s, '(\D*)(\d*)', 'g') r;
$$;
```

The design goals of this function were simplicity and pure string operations (no custom types and no arrays), so it can easily be used as a drop-in solution, and is trivial to be indexed over.

*Note:* If you expect numbers with more than `20` digits, you'll have to replace the hard-coded maximum length `20` in the function with a suitable larger length. Note that this will directly affect the length of the resulting strings, so don't make that value larger than needed.

Comment: This is the correct solution for me using postgres 12.

Comment: don't work correct with negative numbers...