# RegExp: Split string alphanumeric / numeric

Tags: regex, postgresql, split

can you help me to split a string (or preferred if possible, place a blank at every "split" occasion) after every change from alphanumeric to numeric and vice versa ?

So a string like `D2c1 22` should look like `D 2 c 1 22`. Best way from would be to put a blank at every change from alpha-numeric to numeric.

Comment: I can help you but can not do it for you.

Comment: Somewhat related is this question on natural sorting of strings containing mixes of number and non-number sequences. Some of the queries there might prove useful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965463/humanized-or-natural-number-sorting-of-mixed-word-and-number-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach tested with PostgreSQL and verified to work. It's a bit tortured, so performance might be ... interesting.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_cat_agg (
  BASETYPE = anyarray,
  SFUNC = array_cat,
  STYPE = anyarray
);
SELECT array_to_string(array_cat_agg(a), ' ')
FROM regexp_matches('234kjh23ljkgh34klj2345klj', '(\D*)(\d*)', 'g') x(a);
```

We need `array_cat_agg` because regular `array_agg` can't aggregate arrays of arrays.

Alternately, a form of @davidrac's approach that'll work with PostgreSQL and probably perform significantly better (though I haven't tested) is:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
  regexp_replace(
     '234kjh23ljkgh34klj2345klj', '(\d)(\D)', '\1 \2', 'g'
  ), '(\D)(\d)', '\1 \2', 'g');
```

This is executing the replacement in two passes. First it's inserting a space where series of digits end and series of non-digits begin. Then in another pass it's inserting spaces where series of non-digits end and series of digits begin.

**Update**: Here's an improved formulation:

```
SELECT trim(regexp_replace('234kjh23ljkgh34klj2345klj', '(?!\d)(\D+)|(?!\D)(\d+)', '\1\2 ', 'g'));
```

Comment: @davidrac Verified that your 2nd formulation works with Pg. Rephrased for Pg above, along with an earlier (uglier) implementation. +1'd your answer.

Comment: Thanks. But i gut that exact same teststring (234kjh23ljkgh34klj2345klj) as result when i try the above sql with the double regexp_replace

Comment: @calimero Could you be using an old version of PostgreSQL (9.0 or older) from before the `standard_conforming_strings` change? Try `SET standard_conforming_strings = on;` then test again. (This is why you **always mention your PostgreSQL version in questions**). If it works with `standard_conforming_strings` on, then (a) upgrade PostgreSQL and (b) see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS for how to make the query work without upgrading PostgreSQL. Basically, instead of `'\'` use `E'\\'`; double backslashes and use `E''`.

Comment: Its psql 8.1. But i am not allowed to change that parameter (ERROR:  parameter "standard_conforming_strings" cannot be changed). Guess i have to wait till the admin is here

Comment: @calimero No, just rewrite the query to work with your (frankly prehistoric) version of PostgreSQL, as per the docs link above. `'(\d)(\D)'` becomes `E'(\\d)(\\D)` and so on. You need to **urgently** start planning to upgrade your end-of-life and obsolete PostgreSQL by the way, and **always mention your version in questions** especially since it's so incredibly obsolete. See also http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ .

Comment: It works like this now: SELECT regexp_replace(
  regexp_replace(
     '234kjh23ljkgh34klj2345klj', E'(\\d)(\\D)', E'\\1 \\2', 'g'
  ), E'(\\D)(\\d)', E'\\1 \\2', 'g');

Comment: Thanks very much for your help guys!!!  Yes, we already have a running  PSQL 9.2 Instance and working up a new schema for it. But this Query has to be done quickly in the old system, so again, thanks for the great help! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regexp to find the places where it switches:

```
(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)
```

This way:

```
"234kjh23ljkgh34klj2345klj".gsub(/(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)/, " ")
=> "234 kjh 23 ljkgh 34 klj 2345 klj"
```

**Edit:** Without zero length look ahead and look behind:

```
"234kjh23ljkgh34klj2345klj".gsub(/(\d)(\D)/, "#{$1} #{$2}").gsub(/(\D)(\d)/, "#{$2} #{$1}")
=> "23 jk 5 jkgk 5 lk 534 lj"
```

Comment: Pg (9.2 at least) doesn't seem to understand that regexp, unfortunately. `regress=> select regexp_replace( '234kjh23ljkgh34klj2345klj', '(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)', ' ', 'g');`
`ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid` . See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/148

Comment: It probably can't handle zero-length lookahead and lookbehind. in such case you can use something like this approach (This is ruby syntax, so you'll have to adjust):"234kjh23ljkgh34klj2345klj".gsub(/(\d)(\D)/, "#{$1} #{$2}").gsub(/(\D)(\d)/, "#{$2} #{$1}")
=> "23 jk 5 jkgk 5 lk 534 lj"

Comment: Syntax for lookahead in pg (from the doc): (?=re) positive lookahead matches at any point where a substring matching re begins (AREs only)
(?!re) negative lookahead matches at any point where no substring matching re begins (AREs only)

Comment: Thanks so much for that explanation, but can you translate me the above to fit inte pg? I am really not that in regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

> Best way from would be to put a blank at every change from alpha-numeric to numeric.

Its not hard to do:

```
$ echo "D2c1 22" | sed 's|\([a-ZA-Z]\)\([0-9]\)|\1 \2|g;s|\([0-9]\)\([a-ZA-Z]\)|\1 \2|g'
D 2 c 1 22
```

Here I used `sed` and its regexp because you doesn't mention which language you use. Main idea is to use 2 regexp which replaces alpha with digit and digit with alpha to first character, space and second character.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick resonses. I'd like to do it in postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

You can match using the regex

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])
```

and replace it with a space.

[**See it in Perl**](http://ideone.com/Gq61FQ)

Comment: As @davidrac's solution, it seems Pg's regular expression engine doesn't cope with that one. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/148

Comment: Generally better to use `\d` and `\D` too, so you can cope with any digit and non-digit sequences, not just lower-case alphanumeric.