# SQL for comparison of strings comprised of number and text

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, postgresql-9.2, natural-sort

I need to compare 2 strings that contains number and possibly text. for example I have this table:

```
id | label 1  |  label 2 | 
1  |  12/H    |     1    |
2  |   4/A    |    41/D  |
3  |  13/A    |     3/F  |
4  |   8/A    |     8/B  |
..
```

I need to determine the direction so that if Label 1 < Label2 then Direction is W (with) else it is A (against). So I have to build a view that presents data this way:

```
id | Direction  
1  |     A    |   
2  |     W    |
3  |     A    |
4  |     W    |
..
```

I'm using postgres 9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT id
         ,split_part(label1, '/', 1)::int AS l1_nr
         ,split_part(label1, '/', 2)      AS l1_txt
         ,split_part(label2, '/', 1)::int AS l2_nr
         ,split_part(label2, '/', 2)      AS l2_txt
   FROM t
   )
SELECT id
      ,CASE WHEN (l1_nr, l1_txt) < (l2_nr, l2_txt)
       THEN 'W' ELSE 'A' END AS direction
FROM   x;
```

I split the two parts with [`split_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) and check with an ad-hoc row type to check which label is bigger.

The cases where both labels are equal or where either one is NULL have not been defined.

The [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) is not necessary, it's just to make it easier to read.

[-> sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c364b/4)

Comment: To get the A and W, change the 2nd to last line  
SELECT id, case when (l1_nr, l1_txt) < (l2_nr, l2_txt) then 'W' else 'A' end AS direction

Comment: @Gary: Right, I added that, too.

Comment: You may also be interested in this [closely related question by @Craig with a number of solutions for sorting of mixed number-and-text strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965463/humanized-or-natural-number-sorting-of-mixed-word-and-number-strings).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN regexp_replace(label_1,'[^0-9]','','g')::numeric <
                     regexp_replace(label_2,'[^0-9]','','g')::numeric
                THEN 'W'
                ELSE 'A'
           END
FROM table1
```

`regexp_replace` deletes all non numeric characters from the string `::numeric` converts the string to `numeric`.

Details here: [`regexp_replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), [pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), [`CASE WHEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html)