# pgadmin - an error has occurred, column "datconfig" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin

I've a ubuntu server 12.04 running postgresql version 9.1.10, and I've downloaded pgAdmin III 1.8.4 for windows (7, x64).

When I try to estabish a connection I'm getting this message:

```
an error has occurred: ERROR: column "datconfig" does not exist LINE1: ...b.dattablespace AS spccoid, spcname, datallowconn, datconfig, ..."
```

I've googled this and I've only found "upgrade your pgadmin version", but since I'm running the last one...

I appreciate If you could give any assistance.

Comment: `datconfig`, maybe? If it really says `dataconfig` in the error message, then there's a typo in the PgAdmin-III codebase.

Comment: datconfig, thanks, edit.

Comment: the typo was made by me haha

Comment: It looks like `datconfig` was removed in PostgreSQL 9.0. Verify you're actually running the version of PgAdmin-III you think you are.

Comment: the splash screen and the "about" window shows an elephant that says I'm running version 1.8.4 (jun 4 2008, rev 7358)

Comment: Might be worth asking on the pgadmin-support mailing list then.

Comment: I've tried that, I believe, before posting here and it failed: This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Delivery to the following recipients failed.

support@postgresql.org

Comment: Er... that's not `pgadmin-support`.http://www.pgadmin.org/support/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The current version of pgAdmin is **1.18.1**. pgAdmin 1.8.4 is *very old* (released 2007). Hardly works with Postgres 9.1.

Install the current version and try again:
http://pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: of course... 18>8... I've missed that. I've just downloaded the last listed one, and because the list is alphabetically ordered, the 1.8 is the last one. I had found strange that the last one was from 2008. Thank you very much!

Comment: [Sort order isn't always that trivial ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965463/humanized-or-natural-number-sorting-of-mixed-word-and-number-strings) :)