# Sort alphanumeric column

Tags: sql, postgresql, alphanumeric, natural-sort

I have a column in database:

```
Serial Number
-------------
S1
S10
...
S2
S11
..
S13
```

I want to sort and return the result as follows for serial number <= 10 :

```
S1
S2
S10
```

One way I tried was:

```
select Serial_number form table where Serial_Number IN ('S1', 'S2',... 'S10');
```

This solves the purpose but looking for a better way

Comment: For a general solution to this problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965463/humanized-or-natural-number-sorting-of-mixed-word-and-number-strings . It may be unnecessarily complicated if your values are simpler and more consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Postgres you can use something like this:

```
select serial_number
from the_table
order by regexp_replace(serial_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::integer;
```

The `regexp_replace` will remove all non-numeric characters and the result is treated as a number which is suited for a "proper" sorting.

**Edit 1:**

You can use the new  "number" to limit the result of the query:

```
select serial_number
from (
  select serial_number, 
         regexp_replace(serial_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::integer as snum
  from the_table
) t 
where snum <= 10
order by snum;
```

**Edit 2**

If you receive the error `ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""` then apparently you have values in the serial_number column which do no follow the format you posted in your question. It means that regexp_replace() remove all characters from the string, so a string like  `S` would cause that.

To prevent that, you need to either exclude those rows from the result using:

```
where length(regexp_replace(serial_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')) > 0
```

in the inner select. Or, if you need those rows for some reason, deal with that in the select list:

```
select serial_number
from (
  select serial_number, 
         case
            when length(regexp_replace(serial_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')) > 0 then regexp_replace(serial_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::integer as snum
            else null -- or 0 whatever you need
         end as snum
  from the_table
) t 
where snum <= 10
order by snum;
```

---

This is a really nice example on why you should never mix two different things in a single column. If all your serial numbers have a prefix `S` you shouldn't store it and put the real number in a real `integer` (or `bigint`) column.

Using something like `NOT_SET` to indicate a missing value is also a bad choice. The `NULL` value was precisely invented for that reason: to indicate the absence of data.

Comment: Why do we need flag 'g'? Also, is it possible to limit the resultset till say S5 or S10?

Comment: @iDev: just to be sure. If there were other non-numeric characters after the beginning, regexp_replace() with the `g` parameter wouldn't replace them. It make the replace "global" rather than just the firs occurance

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, but I am not sure how could the result only have till S10?

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Comment: @iDev: which means you have rows in there that do not contain any number, e.g. `S`

Comment: Just checked, yes I do have some rows with 'NOT_SET'

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way for this format:

```
order by length(Serial_Number),
         Serial_Number
```

This works because the prefix (`'S'`) is the same length on all the values.

Comment: Thanks didnt realize that it would work for the same prefix. But is there a way that I could limit it till a certain value? Say till S5 or S10?

Comment: @iDev . . . I don't really understand what you mean.  `limit` takes a number of rows, not a value.

Answer (score 1):

Since only the first character spoils your numeric fun, just trim it with [`right()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) and sort by the numeric value:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  right(serial_number, -1)::int < 11
ORDER  BY right(serial_number, -1)::int;
```

Requires Postgres 9.1 or later. In older versions substitute with `substring (x, 10000)`.