# Multilevel list natural sort with regexp

Tags: regex, postgresql, natural-sort

Here is an example of data:

```
'1.'    'Numeric types'
'1.1.'  'Integer'
'1.2.'  'Float'
...
'1.10'  'Double'
```

To naturally sort it we can use `string_to_array` with `'.'` as separator, then cast `text[]` to `int[]` and sort by integer array, but since the field itself is of type `text` and there might be cases where user decides to use non-numeric symbols, e.g. `1.1.3a`, thus causing cast error.
To address that I decided to use regexp:

```
select regexp_matches('1.2.3.4.', E'(?:(\\d+)\.?)+')
```

Expected result is array: `{'1', '2', '3', '4'}` but instead i get only the last element of the said array, however, if I use following regexp:

```
select regexp_matches('1.2.3.4.', E'((?:\\d+)\.?)+')
```

The result is `{'1.2.3.4.'}`.

Using global-flag `'g'` is not an option, because `regexp_matches` returns a column.

Is there any way to convert `'1.2.3.4a.'::text` to `{1, 2, 3 ,4}::int[]` using only one `regexp_matches`?

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d0e4/2).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the global `'g'` flag with `regexp_matches`, but needs to aggregate values to an array (most  simple with the `array()` constructor):

```
select array(select m[1] from regexp_matches(dt_code, '(\d+)', 'g') m)::int[] nums, *
from data_types
order by 1;
```

Or, you can split your string to array with `string_to_array()`, but you still need to use regexp to remove any non-numeric characters:

```
select string_to_array(trim(regexp_replace(dt_code, '[^\d\.]+', ''), '.'), '.')::int[] nums, *
from data_types
order by 1;
```

For a more advanced natural-like sorting, you need to split your text to tokens yourself. See more info at [the related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965463/humanized-or-natural-number-sorting-of-mixed-word-and-number-strings).

I could come up with a simplified, reusable function:

```
create or replace function natural_order_tokens(text)
  returns table (
    txt text,
    num int,
    num_rep text
  )
  language sql
  strict
  immutable
as $func$
  select m[1], (case m[2] when '' then '0' else m[2] end)::int, m[2]
    from regexp_matches($1, '(\D*)(\d*)', 'g') m
   where m[1] != '' or m[2] != ''
$func$;
```

With this function, natural sorting will be this easy:

```
select *
from data_types
order by array(select t from natural_order_tokens(dt_code) t);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/189ba/6)

Comment: Did you even bother to read the question? You simply suggest every approach I stated in my question as inapplicable. Also the question was how to do it using only one `regexp_matches`, and you ignored that as well. What is the point of posting answer again?

Comment: @Nick yes, I read it. None of your approaches work in your question (as you stated), but these are working solutions. Also the *using only one `regexp_matches`* also in this answer (that is the first one). You couldn't do it without the `g` modifier.

Comment: Then the answer is **"No, you can not do it only with a single `regexp_matches` call"**.

Comment: @Nick but i could do it with a single *call* ... (using `g` does not call `regexp_matches` multiple times)

Comment: So you like to remove words from the question to make it easier. I will try once again: **ONLY with a single regexp_matches call**, meaning no other function calls.

Comment: @Nick what other functions do you see in my answer? `array()` and `array[]` are the array constructors, they are language features, not function calls http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS