# Natural sort supporting big numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, natural-sort

I have some data like this:

```
 id | templateName 
----+--------------
 10 | a
 61 | a
 63 | a
  4 | a
  6 | a
  7 | a
 34 | a
 35 | a
 62 | a
  1 | a
 13 | a
 25 | a
 26 | a
 66 | a
 68 | a
 70 | a
 65 | a
  5 | a1
 73 | a5
  3 | a15
  2 | a15a
 69 | a15b
 64 | a15b4
 74 | a15b21
  8 | a214748364
```

I'm doing natural sort with the following code:

```
CREATE TYPE ai AS (a text, i int);

select id, "templateName" from daily_templates
order by ARRAY(SELECT ROW(x[1], CASE x[2] WHEN '' THEN '0' ELSE x[2] END)::ai
               FROM regexp_matches("templateName", '(\D*)(\d*)', 'g')  x)
       , "templateName";
```

And it works well like I show above. Now I want to support large numbers such as

```
a111111111111111111111
```

which will be out of range of `integer`. How can I do that? 
Reference: [Humanized or natural number sorting of mixed word-and-number strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965463/humanized-or-natural-number-sorting-of-mixed-word-and-number-strings)

Comment: If your numbers are not arbitrary large, you can use `BIGINT` (= 8 byte integers) instead of `INT` for `i` in `ai`. For very large numbers `DECIMAL`might be a solution.

Comment: I tried to create i bigint, but it still cast to integer, i think because of the regexp_matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like @clemens suggested. Use `numeric` (= `decimal`) in the composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE ai AS (a text, i numeric);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=11c8e9e6f0b5c63ba3abca354fce64a8)*

The reason I used `int` in the referenced answer is performance.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you have PostgreSQL v10 or better with support for ICU collations, you could

```
CREATE COLLATION natural (provider = icu, locale = 'en-US-u-kn-true');
```

and then sort like this:

```
... ORDER BY "templateName" COLLATE natural
```

Comment: Hi, I jumped into a problem, it's about the performance of sorting. Is there anyway to improve it?

Comment: That probably cannot be helped. The more complicated the collation, the more expensive sorting will be.